# Docker timeout while fetching image on Debian host

Tags: debian, docker

I am running docker on Debian. Since today it works perfect, but today i have serious connection errors from this machine. 
I tried to pull images on my boot2docker maschine, too and it works, but on the debian server it hangs.

```
$ uname -a

Linux hostname.tld 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt2-1~bpo70+1 (2014-12-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo docker version

Client version: 1.4.1 Client API version: 1.16 Go version (client): go1.3.3 Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8 OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64 Server version: 1.4.1 Server API version: 1.16 Go version (server): go1.3.3 Git commit (server): 5bc2ff8

$ docker pull node:latest
Pulling repository node

FATA[0143] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/node/images: read tcp 162.242.195.84:443: i/o timeout
```

I have no ideas why i have a timeout today. Please help me to figure out whats wrong.

here is the log:

```
time="2015-01-31T23:09:21+01:00" level="info" msg="POST /v1.16/images/create?fromImage=node%3Alatest" 
time="2015-01-31T23:09:21+01:00" level="info" msg="+job pull(node, latest)" 
time="2015-01-31T23:09:21+01:00" level="info" msg="+job trust_update_base()" 
time="2015-01-31T23:09:21+01:00" level="info" msg="-job trust_update_base() = OK (0)" 
time="2015-01-31T23:10:21+01:00" level="error" msg="Error from V2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/manifest/library/node/latest: read tcp 162.242.195.84:443: i/o timeout" 
time="2015-01-31T23:11:22+01:00" level="error" msg="Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/node/tags: read tcp 162.242.195.84:443: i/o timeout" 
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/node/tags: read tcp 162.242.195.84:443: i/o timeout
time="2015-01-31T23:11:22+01:00" level="info" msg="-job pull(node, latest) = ERR (1)"
```

Comment: Figured out anything?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a public http proxy to my config.